# MX Record for a physical server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, smtp, email-server, mx-record

I've a physical server which is used as a Mail Transfer Agent(MTA), I'm using `postfix` as SMTP server and `cyrus` as IMAP. I've a static IP for the server and have SSH access to it.

Postfix and cyrus seem to be configured properly, because I can send emails to others. But I can't receive any emails. Probably the reason is I haven't updated the MX Record of my domain which is bought from AWS.

I can't understand **how to update MX Record to receive emails from others**. I mean, what should be the values to be put as MX Record, I only have  the IP address of my server.

More information:
I used `mailx` command to send emails and I successfully received the sent emails in my gmail/outlook/yahoo. But when I reply to those it says:

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
[example.com 54.175.152.x: socket error]
[example.com 107.21.3.x: socket error]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google "how to set an MX record". This is a trivial DNS change, which you do wherever your DNS is hosted - with your domain registrar, or where you've pointed your name servers - which could be your server.

You create the MX record with your domain name, priority 1, with your server IP. If you have a secondary server that can be priority 2 or lower. For one domain you probably don't need a secondary server, as if your server is offline other mail servers will queue mail for it for a while.

I'd have guessed that if there was no MX record other MTA would default to using the A record - though you should check that theory though. You should be very sure your email server is working properly before you point DNS at it. Set up an email server on a PC, change your host file so DNS points at the new server (or you have to install a DNS server since hosts files can only set A records), and see what you find.